# Interrupting a running spring mybatis transaction

Tags: spring, transactions, interrupt, mybatis, spring-transactions

Is it possible with spring and mybatis to interrupt an executing mybatis database transaction?

Example:

I have an application that inserts thousands of records into a oracle SQL database. This takes about 5 minutes. If the user presses the "stop" button while the records are being inserted i want to stop the database transaction and rollback the changes.

I am able to rollback the transaction once the database procedure is finished using the transaction manager:

```
TransactionStatus status = txManager.getTransaction(def);
txManager.rollback(status)
```

But i am unable to interrupt the transaction when it is running.

In JDBC i would simply do: `PreparedStatement.cancel()`

I have tried to obtain this PreparedStatement in MyBatis but i don't think it's possible.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: I can't find a way to do this either.  It would be a nice enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can get current session from session factory and then invoke Session.cancelQuery()  which i think inturn use db call to cancel query execution.

and as per hibernate doc, it is thread safe

[hibernate session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/impl/SessionImpl.html#cancelQuery%28%29)

> Cancel the execution of the current query. This is the sole method on
>   session which may be safely called from another thread.

Comment: I use myBatis in my project not Hibernate, but thanks for the help anyway

Comment: i have not used myBatis, but i think you can still use this solution by getting current open connection/session and then cancel query by aspect.